# Change of numeraire from bank account to Zcb

Tags: stochastic-calculus, convexity

Why is there no drift adjustment when numeraire is changed from bank account (risk neutral measure) to zero coupon bond who matures at time of payoff (fwd risk neutral measure) ?

Comment: I do not know in what context you are saying this. If you assume deterministic interest rates, the the risk-neutral measure and the forward measure are the same. However, with stochastic interest rates, then the drift term will be changed.

Comment: Deterministic interest rates.  Why are the 2 measures the same? They are not - they have different values!

Comment: Maybe the answer is that the volatility of each numeraire is zero ?

Answer (score 3):

Let $B_t= e^{\int_0^t r_sds}$ be the money-market account value at time $t$, and $P(t, T)$ be the value of the zero-coupon bond with maturity $T$ and unit face amount. Moreover, let $Q$ be the risk-neutral measure and $Q_T$ be the $T$-forward measure. If the interest rate $r_t$ is deterministic, then
\begin{align*}
P(t, T) &= E\left(e^{-\int_t^T r_s ds} \,|\, \mathcal{F}_t\right)\\
&= e^{-\int_t^T r_s ds} = \frac{B_t}{B_T},
\end{align*}
where $E$ is the expectation under the risk-neutral measure $Q$. Moreover, 
for $0 \le t \le T$,
\begin{align*}
\frac{dQ}{dQ_T}\big|_t &= \frac{B_t P(0, T)}{P(t, T)}\\
&=\frac{B_t \frac{1}{B_T}}{\frac{B_t}{B_T}}=1.
\end{align*}
In particular, for any $A\in \mathcal{F}_T$, 
\begin{align*}
Q(A) &= \int_{\Omega} \pmb{1}_A dQ \\
&= \int_{\Omega} \pmb{1}_A \frac{dQ}{dQ_T}\big|_T dQ_T \\
&= \int_{\Omega} \pmb{1}_A dQ_T \\
&=Q_T(A).
\end{align*}
That is, $Q=Q_T$.

Comment: Hi gordon in the numeraire of the radon nikodym derivative i think it should just be Bt.  Why do you have Bt x P(0,T)?

Comment: Let $(V_t)_{t \geq 0}$ denote a self-financing portfolio wealth process adapted to the filtration $\Bbb{F} = \{ (\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0} \}$. Under the measure $\Bbb{Q}$ associated to the numéraire $B_t$ one should have $$ \frac{V_0}{B_0} = \Bbb{E}_0^\Bbb{Q} \left[ \frac{V_t}{B_t} \right] $$Similarly, under $\Bbb{Q}^T$ associated to $P(t,T)$, $$ \frac{V_0}{P(0,T)} = \Bbb{E}_0^\Bbb{Q} \left[ \frac{V_t}{P(t,T)} \right] $$

Comment: Hence indeed: $$ V_0 = \Bbb{E}_0^\Bbb{Q} \left[ V_t \frac{B_0}{B_t} \right] = \Bbb{E}_0^\Bbb{Q^T} \left[ V_t \frac{P(0,T)}{P(t,T)} \right] $$ hence indeed
$$ \left. \frac{d\Bbb{Q}}{d\Bbb{Q}^T} \right\vert_{\mathcal{F}_t} = \frac{B_t  P(0,T) }{ B_0 P(t,T) } $$ with $B_0=1$

Comment: Thanks @Quantuple for your clarification. Indeed, the Radon-NiKodym derivative can be treated as the ratio of the **normalized** numeraires, that is, $\frac{B_t}{B_0}$ and $\frac{P(t, T)}{P(0, T)}$.

Comment: No problem @Gordon

Comment: thanks very much.  i guess also , if one wanted an intuitive reason why both measures are the same (assuming deterministic interest rates), it would be because both measures grow at the same rate ?

Comment: @Randor: I do not recommend to say that as it is not clear why there is a growth rate. Instead, you can say that the Radon-NiKodym derivative is 1.